# Members divided by remainder series diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We have a series $a(k)$ with positive (real) members. We know that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a(k)$ is convergent. Let $r(k)$ be $\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}a(j)$. Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(k)}{r(k)}$ diverges.

I have tried the ratio, root and condensation tests but none of them yielded anything.

Comment: @user328442 That it converges also?

Comment: @user328442 $\sum_{0}^{\infty} a(k)-\sum_{0}^{k} a(k)$?

Comment: @user328442 sorry, I don't see how to finish it

Comment: This has been asked several times on the site already. The idea is to look at the tails of the transformed series. Namely, fix some finite $k$ and consider the partial sums $$\sum_{i=k}^{n-1}\frac{a(i)}{r(i)}\geqslant\sum_{i=k}^{n-1}\frac{a(i)}{r(k)}={}{}{}{}\frac{r(k)-r(n)}{r(k)}.$$ Now, when $n\to\infty$, $r(n)\to0$ hence there exists some $n$ such that $r(n)\leqslant\frac12r(k)$, which yields $$\sum_{i=k}^{n-1}\frac{a(i)}{r(i)}\geqslant\frac12.$$ Since the tails of $\sum\limits_n\frac{a(n)}{r(n)}$ do not converge to zero, this series diverges.

Comment: @user328442 You seem to be leading the OP to a deadend.

Comment: @Did thanks, but could you link to the previous ones so I can accept it as a duplicate